# MySQL left join subquery fail

Tags: mysql, subquery, left-join

Following query runs well in MySQL 5.x

```
SELECT
  m_area.id, m_area.cn_areaName, m_area.de_areaName,
  m_area.en_areaName,m_area.jp_areaName,t_shop.count
FROM
  m_area left join   
(
select t_shop.areaID, count(areaID) AS count
from t_shop
group by t_shop.areaID
) t_shop
on m_area.id = t_shop.areaID
```

However, when I have to run it in a 4.0.23 MySQL DB with same DB structure and data it just return following message:

> ## 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax.  Check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '[
>
> ```
>             select t_shop.areaID, count(areaID) AS count
>             from t_s
> ```

I tried many times but still failed. Is left join to subquery not allowed in MySQL 4.x ? Then that mean I have to do it with a temp table?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

take out ", count(areaID) AS count"

The multiple columns in the subquery is messing up the join.

A temp table should work fine ....

Have fun!

Comment: You are right I can only do that with temp tab

DROP TEMPORARY TABLE IF EXISTS temp_shop;
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE temp_shop ( areaID int(11), count int(11) ); 

INSERT INTO temp_shop 
select t_shop.areaID, count(areaID) AS count
    from t_shop
    group by t_shop.areaID;

SELECT
      m_area.id, m_area.cn_areaName, m_area.de_areaName,
      m_area.en_areaName,m_area.jp_areaName,temp_shop.count
    FROM
      m_area left join temp_shop
    on m_area.id = temp_shop.areaID;


Sometimes we have to code for some old machines, which is so painful.

Answer (score 4):

Subqueries were quite not well supported with MySQL 4.0 : it became possible to use them *(at least, in some real, useful way)* with MySQL 4.1 -- and MySQL 4.0 is really old, now...

See for instance this page of the MySQL manual : [12.2.8. Subquery Syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/4.1/en/subqueries.html) *(quoting, emphasis mine)* :

> **Starting with MySQL 4.1**, all subquery forms and operations that the
>   SQL standard requires are supported,
>   as well as a few features that are
>   MySQL-specific.
>
> With MySQL versions prior to 4.1, it
>   was necessary to **work around or
>   avoid the use of subqueries**. 
> In
>   many cases, subqueries can
>   successfully be rewritten using joins
>   and other methods. See [Section
>   12.2.8.11, “Rewriting Subqueries as Joins for Earlier MySQL Versions”](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/4.1/en/rewriting-subqueries.html).

Comment: The link you've provided essentialy says that what OP does is the solution to the problem you mention?!

Answer (score 1):

Only thing I could think of is adding the tablename to your areaID in the subquery or renaming the reserved word `count` to cnt.

```
SELECT  m_area.id
        , m_area.cn_areaName
        , m_area.de_areaName
        , m_area.en_areaName
        ,m_area.jp_areaName
        ,t_shop.cnt
FROM     m_area 
        left join ( 
          select     t_shop.areaID
                    , count(t_shop.areaID) AS cnt 
          from       t_shop 
          group by   t_shop.areaID 
        ) t_shop on m_area.id = t_shop.areaID
```